# Can I recover a deleted partition table faster if I remember some of the layout?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, testdisk

I accidentally deleted the partition table of a 1.5TB drive with about 10 partitions on it; I'm running `testdisk` now but it's going to take a while to scan everything.

I do have some useful information which I'm hoping can speed things up - the partition layout and filesystem types (mostly NTFS, some FAT32, EXT3/4). Unfortunately there are a few unknowns with the partition sizes. I do have another disk with a backup of (most) of the partitions, but there may still be some unknowns.

Is there any way to use the information I do have to speed up the partition table recovery, or do I just need to wait for the exhaustive scan to finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### No - not recommended, can cause irretrievable data loss

Unless you have **all** the information `fdisk -l` provides, you shouldn't attempt this. Just knowing the filesystems isn't going to help much (yet); the start and end are what matter most.

Let `testdisk` run and take its own time -- it usually does a very good job.