# Rerstore partition table which was deleted accidently

Tags: partitioning, gparted

while using Gparted I accidently clicked **new partition** and selected **msdos** now my 3 partition hdd shows only one unalocated drive. I didn't do anything else after that. I recovered one drive using parted with **rescue** command but i cannot find the other partitions with the **parted** command. I still have two partitions on the hdd which contains data. Now what to do? i need the partitions really bad.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try testdisk and see if it can work it's magic

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I recover a deleted partition table faster if I remember some of the layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158220/can-i-recover-a-deleted-partition-table-faster-if-i-remember-some-of-the-layout)

Comment: @guiverc Thank you for your response, i have tried the official documentation but after finding one partition the rescue operation couldn't find more.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Thank you for your comment, i'm using testdisk now. Could you please give me a detailled link so that i could understand easily.